# Making a handle for a bottle with a rounded grip for fingers

Tags: modeling

[image]I am new to blender and the 3d modeling world.  I have modeled a metal mug and am trying to match the lid.  I can get it most of the way.  But when I try to make the actual handle I use boolean to do the circle cutouts and it makes the handle all wonky. I have tried making the inside of the handle completely filled and then tried using the boolean. but the same thing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Handle should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I deleted the handle part and am trying to figure out the best route to take from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it this way:

- At first, to make the base, use an *Array* then a *Simple Deform* / *Bend* mode. At the end, keep a copy then apply both the 2 modifiers, then use a *Mirror* on X and Y as the object is symmetrical on these axis.

[image]

- To create the handle you'll begin to extrude some faces of the base. Use your picture as a background to make sure you follow the shape.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thank you.  That is awesome. I appreciate the detailed answer.  This is the route I will take.